# Can't find variable: function() using evaluateJavaScript("function()") in WKWebview and react js

Tags: javascript, swift, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an hybrid application that uses WKWebview and React js(hooks).
I need to send user id to web from Ios.(Javascript -> IOS)
I am trying to do it using evaluateJavaScript().

the method will work if I put my function in  tag of index.html,
it would not work if I put it in the component.
the error will be returned

> Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "JavaScript error occured" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: undefined is not a function, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript error occured})

In my IOS side didFinish navigation(WKWebviewController)

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    //success
    let myJsFuncName1 = "getUserIdFromNativeOnIndexHtml('jack123')"
    self.webview.evaluateJavaScript(myJsFuncName1) { (result, error) in
    if let result = result{ print(result) }else{
        print("error2",error)
    } }

    //fail
    let myJsFuncName2 = "getUserIdFromNativeOnTheComponentJS('clever123')"
    self.webview.evaluateJavaScript(myJsFuncName2) { (result, error) in
    if let result = result{ print(result) }else{
        print("error3",error)
    } }
}
```

Javascript

in index.html

```
///this will work
<script type="text/JavaScript" charset="UTF-8">
function getUserIdFromNativeOnIndexHtml(id) {
                    alert('user is ' + id + '!!');
                }
            </script>
```

myCouponList.js

```
function MyCouponList(props) {
const classes = useStyles(props);


function getUserIdFromNativeOnTheComponentJS(id) {
    alert('user is ' + id + '!!');
}


return (
    <>
        <header className={classes.header}>
            <div className={classes.header__header_column}>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    className={classes.header_backButton}
                    onClick={() => window.webkit.messageHandlers.goBackButton.postMessage('goBackButton')}
                >
                    <img src="/assets/images/banto/backButton.png" alt="backButton" />
                </button>{' '}
            </div>{' '}
            <div className={classes.header__header_column}>
                <h1 className={classes.header__title}> 쿠폰 </h1>{' '}
            </div>{' '}
            <div className={classes.header__header_column}>
                <span className={classes.header__icon}>
                    <i className="fas fa-search"> </i>{' '}
                </span>
                <span className={classes.header__icon}>
                    <i className="fas fa-cog"> </i>{' '}
                </span>{' '}
            </div>{' '}
        </header>{' '}
        {}....
```

I want to save userid in reducer to make API call.